# Do mophological ops have a bug when using a header vs full matrix copy source?

Tags: c++, opencv, copy-constructor, image-morphology

Opencv 2.4.10.
At the end of the code below, a dilation is called with a 9 wide disk structuring element on a matrix, Img2.  Originally, Img2 was created from Img1 by a simple header copy (Img2=Img1).  Note, Img1 was made without copying data from Img0 via Ranges such that Img1 doesn't have the first and last 3 rows of Img0.  The result of the dilation was incorrect.

However, if I used a full copy for Img2 via clone, Img2=Img1.clone(), the dilation worked correctly.

Note that using imwrite, not shown in the code below, on Img2 was the same regardless of which copy method I used.  So, shouldn't the morphological operators work the same too?

```
Mat Tmp;
Mat Img1=Img0(Range(3-1, Img0.rows - 3+1),Range::all());

Img1(Range(0,1), Range::all()) = 0;
Img1(Range(Img1.rows-1,Img1.rows), Range::all()) = 0;

// bad
//Mat Img2 = Img1; // header only copy: the dilation results are wrong on the top and bottom 
// good
Mat Img2 = Img1.clone();  // full copy, dilation works right.

Mat Disk4;
// exact replacement for mmatlab strel('disk',4,0), somewhat difference   than opencv's ellipse structuring element.
MakeFilledEllipse( 4, 4, Disk4);  


// If I use Img2 from clone, this is the same as matlab's.  
// If I just do a header copy some areas the top and bottom are different
dilate(Img2, Tmp,Disk4, Point(-1,-1),1,BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar(0));
```

**EDIT**- I subsequently simplified the code so that Img2 replaces img1 and there is no img1 so that I could repeat the problem with only 1 level of Mat header indirection and it still failed (was incorrect) the same way.

```
Mat Tmp;
Mat Img2=Img0(Range(3-1, Img0.rows - 3+1),Range::all());

Img2(Range(0,1), Range::all()) = 0;
Img2(Range(Img2.rows-1,Img2.rows), Range::all()) = 0;

Mat Disk4;
// exact replacement for mmatlab strel('disk',4,0), somewhat difference   than opencv's ellipse structuring element.
MakeFilledEllipse( 4, 4, Disk4);  

// bad result   
dilate(Img2, Tmp,Disk4, Point(-1,-1),1,BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

`Mat` became non-continuous in effect of selecting a ROI within itself.

I'm not sure that in your case `Mat Mat::operator()( Range _rowRange, Range _colRange ) const` will set `CONTINUOUS_FLAG` to false but the `SUBMATRIX_FLAG` will be set surely which can lead to different operation.

Here, I guess some parts of `cv::dilate()` (such as the border pixel extrapolation method, or the structuring element that determines the shape of a pixel neighborhood) affect your output if there are pixels in the original image around your ROI.

I suggest to use the following to reorder the memory before calling `cv::dilate()`:

```
if (!mat.isContinuous() || mat.isSubmatrix())
{ 
    mat = mat.clone();
}
```